# Getting currently opened tabs from stock browser

Tags: android, plugins, browser

Is there a way to get all the URLs from currently opened tabs in Android programmatically? I know there's a way to read browser history but I need a way to detect active tabs and URLs contained. Any ideas?

Comment: you mean the tabs of the browser! I do not think this can be done except if you use your own webviews

Comment: I want the URLs basically. So I'm not sure if this can be done too.

Comment: Any luck with this mate? I am looking for a similar problem

Comment: Any luck with this ? I am also looking for a similar problem @Ramesh